# How can I handle asynchronous processing within quill.clipboard.addMatcher when using the quill.js library in Tauri?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, quill

How can I handle asynchronous processing within `quill.clipboard.addMatcher` when using the quill.js library in Tauri? Specifically, I'm struggling to extract and use the result from a promise returned by the `invoke` function within the matcher callback.

In Tauri, I'm using the quill.js library. I want to find images when a user pastes content, send the image URLs to the backend, download the images locally on the backend, and then return the local URLs. However, I'm unsure how to achieve this.

I've discovered the `quill.clipboard.addMatcher('img', function(node, delta) { ... })` method, which allows me to access the 'img' nodes in the clipboard. I've attempted to implement it as follows:

```js
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('img', function(node, delta) {
    return new Delta().insert({image: localize(node.src)});
});

async function localize(node){
    let src = node.src;
    if (src.slice(0, 4) === 'http') {
        console.log(`${src} begins with http`);
    }
    return invoke('localize', {src: src});
}
```

However, the `invoke` function, which calls the backend code, returns a promise. I'm unsure how to extract the URL from the promise and return a processed delta object within the `addMatcher` callback.

I'm open to alternative solutions. Perhaps I should provide a function to `addMatcher` that calls an async function that directly scans the HTML document for '`img`' nodes and replaces them then return the unaltered `delta`.

Comment: maybe I can just put a button `<button id="loc">localize images</button>` and add a listener `document.getElementById('loc').onclick = () => {localizeNodes(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));}`

Comment: I just find a similar case in github [Uploading images when paste rich text into the editor](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2214)